# Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 500 when using map_df

Tags: r, web-scraping, try-catch, rvest

I get the error when trying to scrape a news website. I checked, and the website page 32 is broken. I would like to skip the error and keep scraping the rest of the urls.

I have tried the function TryCatch to avoid the broken link, but since I am quite new to R I do not know how to properly write the code. Should I wrap the read_html with that function? If so, how?

```
url_silla <- 'https://lasillavacia.com/buscar/farc?page=%d'

map_df(0:573, function(i) {

  pagina <- read_html(sprintf(url_silla, i, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'))
  print(i)

  data.frame(titles = html_text(html_nodes(pagina,".col-sm-12 h3")),
             date = html_text(html_nodes(pagina, ".date.col-sm-3")),
             category = html_text(html_nodes(pagina, ".category.col-sm-9")),
             tags = html_text(html_nodes(pagina, ".tags.col-sm-12")),
             link = paste0("https://www.lasillavacia.com",str_trim(html_attr(html_nodes(pagina, "h3 a"), "href"))),
            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}) -> noticias_silla
```

Here is the error. Thanks a lot for any help!

```
[1] 31
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 500.
Called from: open.connection(x, "rb")
```

Comment: Does this previous post help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/12193779/5325862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `purrr::possibly`:

```
url_silla <- 'https://lasillavacia.com/buscar/farc?page=%d'

library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

map_df(0:573, possibly(~{

    pagina <- read_html(sprintf(url_silla, .x, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'))

    print(.x)

    data.frame(titles = html_text(html_nodes(pagina,".col-sm-12 h3")),
               date = html_text(html_nodes(pagina, ".date.col-sm-3")),
               category = html_text(html_nodes(pagina, ".category.col-sm-9")),
               tags = html_text(html_nodes(pagina, ".tags.col-sm-12")),
               link = paste0("https://www.lasillavacia.com",str_trim(html_attr(html_nodes(pagina, "h3 a"), "href"))),
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

}, NULL)) -> noticias_silla
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a `tryCatch` into a function, then pass that function to `map_dfr`. Set it to return `NULL` in the event of an error, which won't break the creation of the data frame by `map_dfr`.

I'd recommend first trying it with `map` instead, so you can investigate how some indices return the data frame you want, and some return `NULL`. In either event, the `finally` argument will print the index.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rvest)

url_silla <- 'https://lasillavacia.com/buscar/farc?page=%d'

read_page <- function(i) {
  tryCatch(
    {
      pagina <- read_html(sprintf(url_silla, i, '%s'))
      data.frame(titles = html_text(html_nodes(pagina,".col-sm-12 h3")),
                 date = html_text(html_nodes(pagina, ".date.col-sm-3")),
                 category = html_text(html_nodes(pagina, ".category.col-sm-9")),
                 tags = html_text(html_nodes(pagina, ".tags.col-sm-12")),
                 link = paste0("https://www.lasillavacia.com", trimws(html_attr(html_nodes(pagina, "h3 a"), "href"))),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    },
    error = function(cond) return(NULL),
    finally = print(i)
  )
}

noticias <- map_dfr(30:33, read_page)
#> [1] 30
#> [1] 31
#> [1] 32
#> [1] 33
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below only processes pages numbers 31, 32 and 33.

I am not going to use `map_*` to solve the problem I believe that it might make things more difficult than what they are. I am going to use a standard `for` loop, since there is no reason why not to.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

url_silla <- 'https://lasillavacia.com/buscar/farc?page=%d'

pages <- 31:33
noticias_silla <- vector("list", length = length(pages))

for(i in pages){
  p <- sprintf(url_silla, i, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
  pagina <- tryCatch(read_html(p),
                     error = function(e) e)
  print(i)
  if(inherits(pagina, "error")){
    noticias_silla[[i - pages[1] + 1]] <- list(page_num = i, page = p)
  }else{
    noticias_silla[[i - pages[1] + 1]] <- data.frame(titles = html_text(html_nodes(pagina,".col-sm-12 h3")),
                                           date = html_text(html_nodes(pagina, ".date.col-sm-3")),
                                           category = html_text(html_nodes(pagina, ".category.col-sm-9")),
                                           tags = html_text(html_nodes(pagina, ".tags.col-sm-12")),
                                           link = paste0("https://www.lasillavacia.com",str_trim(html_attr(html_nodes(pagina, "h3 a"), "href"))),
                                           stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  }
}

lapply(noticias_silla, class)    noticias_silla[[1]]
noticias_silla[[2]]

#[[1]]
#[1] "data.frame"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "list"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "data.frame"    noticias_silla[[1]]
noticias_silla[[2]]
```

Note that the second list member is a `"list"`, not a `"data.frame"`. This is the one where the error occurred.

```
noticias_silla[[2]]
#$page_num
#[1] 32
#
#$page
#[1] "https://lasillavacia.com/buscar/farc?page=32"
```